# jQuery dialog won't open on iphone with private browsing on

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I have a form with some javascript that fires a jquery modal.

The page in question can be found here: http://www.cornerstws.com/modaltest/modaltest.html

When you click on the 'add to cart' button, the modal fires. This works fine on the desktop. However on my iphone, it works fine, UNLESS I use private browsing. Then the modal does NOT fire.

Is there any way around this, or am I missing something?

The function to call the dialog:

```
$(function () {
  $('#thedialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    hide: 'fold',
    show: 'blind',
    position: {
      my: "center", 
      at: "center",
      of: window.top
    },
    open: function (event, ui) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        $('#thedialog').dialog('close'); 
      }, 2000) }
   });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. haven't been able to find anything on Google, while I'm sure I'm not the only one....

Comment: Does the dialog open at all or just the Modal screening is missing?

Comment: @Twisty The 'dialog'/modal opens when you click the 'add to cart' button... unless  you're in the private browsing mode. Then the modal does not open at all. Other than that, everything else in the script works. (adding the actual item to the cart)

Comment: Does this only happen in Safari on the iPhone?

Comment: @Twisty As far as I can see, yes... I've tried incognito browsing in Firefox on the desktop and then it does not happen.